# How to stop the browser window from resizing after a specific size

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, browser

How to give a minimum width to the browser window, so that the user can't make it smaller after a specific size. But he can make it larger than that. Something like applying the 'min-width' property of css to the browser window itself. Is it possible any way?

Comment: What about CSS query media?

Answer (score 6):

You can **not** control the size of the window. You can use CSS to set `min-width` and `min-height` properties to ensure your page layout stays sane.

Comment: using 'window.open' I can open a page with a fixed height width. Is there no similar way to give min-height min-width like this?

Comment: No there is not. You shouldn't really need to though. Make it obvious to your visitor when their window is too small (scrollbars, overflowing w/e) or go all out and make a responsive UI, this is popular for mobile devices.

Comment: Ya I know about responsive thing, but I have a situation and requirement to do this like that only.

Comment: Well, it's technically impossible (in the literal sense of the word 'technical'). Whoever made the requirements doesn't understand this aspect of the web.

Answer (score 1):

You wont be able to affect the client size browser window with CSS. The CSS min/max widths will stop the content from 'shrinking' beyond a certain point, but you cannot (rightly so) prevent the user from controlling the size of their own browser.

You may be able to do it using JavaScript, but then you need to ask the question WHY are you doing this - if its for a design then I'd seriously question the quality of the design.